# hadoop hive --auxpath is not picking up the jars for hive over base

Tags: hadoop, jar, hive, hbase

`hive --auxpath ...`. Somehow it worked in one hadoop client machine and failed under the other. Looks like the failed one did not pick up the jars in auxpath. What could cause the problem?

The command:

```
hive --auxpath /etc/hbase/conf.dist/hbase-site.xml,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.12.0.2.0.6.1-101.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-101.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/hive/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar -hiveconf hbase.zookeeper.quorum=xxx -hiveconf zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure -f hive_over_hbase.hive
```

Outputs:

```
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir.recursive is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.max.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.rack is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.min.split.size.per.node is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
14/06/13 17:28:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks.speculative.execution is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.reduce.speculative

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-0.12.0.2.0.6.1-101.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

Comment: More details? E.g., the exception log?

Comment: the path of `--auxpath` must be absolute path, or something like `file:///.abc.jar`

Comment: hive --auxpath /etc/hbase/conf.dist/hbase-site.xml,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-0.12.0.2.0.6.1-101.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5.2.0.6.0-101.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar,/usr/lib/hive/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-0.96.1.2.0.6.1-101-hadoop2.jar -hiveconf hbase.zookeeper.quorum=xxx -hiveconf zookeeper.znode.parent=/hbase-unsecure -f hive_over_hbase.hive